# Cycle2 Carousel not working when it's in a DIV

Tags: html, css, carousel, laravel-blade, cycle2

So I have a cycle2 Carousel in my page, which worked perfectly. Now I've been putting the content of the carousel in a DIV so I can show content over the images when it's being hovered.

The carousel works as it should when I remove that div (img_ct) but I need that div there to use the hover effect. Any idea where it goes wrong? Below the code being used:

```
<div class="cycle-slideshow" style="width:auto;"
 data-cycle-fx=carousel
 data-cycle-timeout=4000
 data-cycle-prev="> .cycle-prev"
 data-cycle-next="> .cycle-next"
 >

@foreach ($elements['instagram-highlights']['subs'] as $item)

    <div class="img_ct">
        <img class="instagram-home-items" src="{{ $item['instagram-items']['image'] }}">

        <div class="text-content">
            {!! $item['instagram-items']['textfield'] !!}
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach

    <div class= "cycle-prev slider-nav-insta"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></div>
    <div class= "cycle-next slider-nav-insta"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></div>
```

And the CSS (which includes the hover etc):

```
    .text-content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: rgba(29, 106, 154, 0.72);
    color: #fff;
    display:none;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition:opacity 0.2s;
}

.img_ct{
    position:relative;
    width:33%;
    float:left;
}


.instagram-home-items{
    display:block;
}

.img_ct:hover .text-content {
    display:block;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

**EDIT: The code Zgood provided works, but now the CSS screws up a bit. The hover should only be on the item that is actually being hovered, but it goes on all the items. Any idea's on that?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you need is the `slides` option on the [API page](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/api/).

> A selector string which identifies the elements within the slideshow
>   container that should become slides. By default, Cycle2 finds all
>   image elements that are immediate children of the slideshow container.

So in your case you would need that `slides` value to be `> .img_ct`. Since you are declaring it with the `data-` attributes your code might look like this:

```
<div class="cycle-slideshow" style="width:auto;"
 data-cycle-slides="> .img_ct"
 data-cycle-fx="carousel"
 data-cycle-timeout="4000"
 data-cycle-prev="> .cycle-prev"
 data-cycle-next="> .cycle-next"
 >
```

**Update**

For your updated problem, it probably has to do with this style:

```
.img_ct:hover .text-content {
    display:block;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Cycle2 will put an active class on slide that are currently active. Its called `.cycle-slide-active`. So I think you should update the above style to only target active slides. Like this:

```
.img_ct.cycle-slide-active:hover .text-content {
        display:block;
        opacity: 1;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It does work indeed, but now the CSS screws up a bit. The hover is going fullwidth, over all the images in the carousel. Any idea's on that maybe?

Comment: @StefanNeuenschwander Please check and see if my update helps you at all

Comment: It's fixed, my css was overwritten by the one from the plugin, should've known that.. The solution to the css problem was adding !important to the .img_ct div. Thanks for your help zgood!